# creating a dummy variable combining other dummies in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to combine three dummy variables into one. For example:

x1: 1 0 0 0 1

x2: 0 0 0 0 1

x3: 1 1 0 0 0

I want to create:
x4: 1 1 0 0 1 (Takes 1 if any of the three dummies has 1, and takes 0 if all of them are zero)

Note: They are variables in a data frame. So the new variable will be a part of that data frame too.

I am new in python and I appreciate your help. Best

Comment: What are the types of `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`?

Comment: They are all numpy.int64.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you define `x` as a grid:

```
x = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

For each row, we can use `any()` to see if any of the items in the row is one.  We can then turn the result (a boolean) into an integer with `int()`:

```
result = [int(any(row)) for row in x]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what you mean by the new variable being part of the data frame.

I think the most literal way to create x4 is by using a bitwise OR operator in a list comprehension:

```
>>> x1=[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> x2=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>> x3=[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> x4=[x1[i]|x2[i]|x3[i] for i in range(len(x1))]
>>> x4
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

The list comprehension (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) builds a new list while iterating over the first, second, etc values of x1-x3. The bitwise OR operator (|) (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) each time evaluates to 1 if any of the 3 values is 1 and to 0 otherwise.